# Search doesn't work in android SDK offline docs

Tags: android, documentation, offline

I downloaded [docs-24-r01](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/docs-24_r01.zip)
Because in my SDK manager in the android studio under no API there was a documentation to download so I got in manually.I extracted the files inside:

```
sdk:/docs
```

I changed jdk.table.xml and now android studio opens these files as default instead of opening the online version. The only problem is the search doesn't work. I opened index.html files with chrome and tried to search it just loads the same pages.
The URL for example for searching Notification in training I get is:

```
sdk/docs/training/index.html?q=Notification
```